# How to check the condition inside while loop for multiple times and then execute the command

Tags: bash, shell-script

```bash
switchback(){
  while true 
    do
      players=$(cat $serverpath/$port//count.txt);
      sleep 5;
      if (( $players < 10 )); then
        $(loadpubserveripip)
        break
      fi
    done
}
```

In the above function how can I do it like the `if` condition should be `true` for consecutive 5 times and then only it does the further operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a counter variable equal to 5. Decrement by 1 if condition is true, reset to 5 if false, break if count=0. The most trivial answer based on your code:

```
switchback(){
    count=5
    while true 
    do
      players=$(cat $serverpath/$port//count.txt);
      if (( $players < 10 ));then
        if ! ((--count)); then
          $(loadpubserveripip)
          break
        fi
      else
        count=5
      fi
      sleep 5
    done
}
```

Few notes:

- I moved the `sleep 5` to the bottom of the loop, to avoid unnecessary sleep at the last loop.
- The "further operation" could be moved from before the `break` to after the loop, since the loop will only break the 5th time `$players` is less than 10.
- I hope you know what your doing with the `$(loadpubserveripip)` line, the result of `loadpubserveripip` should be a valid shell command for it to work.